# Should there be arrows in a lightbox on mobile?

Tags: mobile, navigation, lightbox

So I found that the PhotoSwipe lightbox disables the left right arrows on mobile devices (when it detects them as touch, which can be a hit and miss). But I wonder why. I know the native gallery apps just expect you to swipe all day, but I don't think the arrows have no use. I'd rather tap in one place continuously than go through an album of hundreds of photos by swiping.

Tapping the UI hides all controls letting people swipe without any distraction, so there is that. On this screenshot I enabled them and they don't feel abnormal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In tests I ran with users in the past I noticed that some of them swipe on galleries and others tap on the arrows. I would keep them. If the users wish to see the picture full size without arrows or other UI elements, they just double-tap and the image will cover the entire screen.